# What's the probability that the smoke will be detected by device $B$ given that it is not detected by device $A$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A smoke-detector system uses two devices, $A$ and $B$. If smoke is present, it will be detected by device $A$ with probability
of $0.93$, by device $B$ with probability of $0.96$; and by both devices with probability of $0.91$.

What's the probability that the smoke will be detected by device $B$ given that it is not detected by device $A$?

I'm not quite sure how to determine the probability of device $B$, given that $A$ fails. I think there is a formula for conditions like that, but I can't find it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Pr(B\mid A^c) = \dfrac{\Pr(B\cap A^c)}{\Pr(A^c)}$ by definition of conditional probability.

Next, $\Pr(B\cap A^c) = \Pr(B)-\Pr(B\cap A)$ by total probability.

Finally, $\Pr(A^c)=1-\Pr(A)$, again by total probability.

Answer (score 0):

In general, given two events $A$ and $B$, the probability of $A$ given $B$ occurs is $P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.
Of course, we need that $P(B)>0$ for this.

Comment: So in this scenario would I get $\frac{0.91}{0.93}$? Since the probability that they both occur is 0.91 and A has already happened & it's probability was 0.93.

Comment: No. I just gave you the general definition. In your case you are interested in the probability of B given that A hasn't occur, which is the same as the probability of B given that $A^\complement$ occurs (since $A^\complement$ is the opposite event of $A$). This is expressed by $P(B\mid A^\complement)$. Are you able to use/addapt the formula I gave you with this information? You will need to calculate a couple of things.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense. I can definitely take it from there.